# QPSQL driver on kubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, python, ubuntu, pyqt5

I am migrating a plugin to (K)Ubuntu 18.04 and QGIS 3.2 but oddly enough I can't seem to connect to a postgres database.

As far as I can see the QPSQL driver is not loaded.
I ran the following code:

```
>>> qgis.PyQt.QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()
['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QSPATIALITE', 'SKGSQLCIPHER']
```

As you can see the QPSQL driver is not loaded. Is there something I am missing?

Extra information
- I am also running a local Postgresql9.6 (so there should be plenty of libs available)
- Latest versions of libpq-dev and libpq5 installed.
- I can load postgis layers from qgis just fine

Comment: Maybe Qt is not used for database access in QGis?

Comment: Thing is, in windows it does show up. I've done a complete reinstall, but still same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by installing the library libqt5sql5-psql

```
sudo apt install libqt5sql5-psql
```

Comment: It took way too much googling to find how to install QPSQL on Ubuntu, thanks!